# How the following expression is working i=+i*i;?

Tags: expression

I have found a expression like :

```
int i=2;
i=+i*i;
```

It produce i=4. I would like someones opinion about it.

Comment: What is mysterious about it? +2*2 is 4

Answer (score 1):

i assume it is some C-like language. In this case there is an "unary plus" operator which looks like `+i` and returns value of `i`.

So according to [operator prescendence rules](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) `i=+i*i;` breaks down to `i = ((+ i) * i)` which basically is equivalent to `i *= i`.

As we know 2 * 2 = 4, so the result you got is totally legitimate.